# Change web page content and browser's download ASP.net web from

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I'm working with ASP.net web form.

Clients can download file with this fucntion :

```
    private void ExporterFichier(string fileName, string fileType, string content)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Server.UrlPathEncode(fileName));
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = fileType;
        Response.Output.Write(content);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

The thing is, i would like to show some informations about the file being downloaded AS it is downloaded.

For Exemple, if i download a files with 457 lines of text, i would like to show a label on the page with :

> "The file contains 457 lines"

But when i do this :

```
    protected void btnAG_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       lbl.Text = AllTheLines.Count().ToString() + " lines";

       ExporterFichier("s.csv", "text/csv", s);
    }
```

The text is not showing, in fact, whatever i do or where i place the modifications (before or after the dowload function), nothing ever happens EXEPT the download.

Is it even possible to modify the content of the page and download a file in the same function ? Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: It doesn't show the  text changes because you're ending the response. The solution is to do the file download in a separate tab/window.

Comment: You have only one response back, but you try to make them two different, you can not do that... think of an alternative approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again Mason,

One way is to call the dowload function in separate tab, then close that tab just after the download, quick enough so users don't get confused with that new tab. So the first page is always free to write it's own response.

**Content page :**

```
 protected void btnAG_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int id_sdg = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAG.SelectedValue);

     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(), 
        "OpenWindow", 
        "window.open('Telecharge.aspx?idSdg=" + id_sdg.ToString() + "','_newtab');",
        true);

     courriels.Count().ToString() + " Emails detected";
 }
```

**Download page :**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id_sdg = Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request["idSdg"]);

        using (DAL.AGEntities db = new DAL.AGEntities())
        {
            var courriels = BigQuery(db);

            string liste = BLL.ConstructeurString.BuildCsv(courriels);

            ExporterFichier("ListeCourriels-" + id_sdg.ToString() + ".csv", "text/csv", liste);
        }
    }
```